# Getting the bitmap of the ViewGroup alone

Tags: android, android-view

I have a ViewGroup with several children, and I want to be able to get the bitmap of the view group itself, before any of its children are added. I need it because I want to rotate the bitmap without affecting the children. Is there any way to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the `onDraw` function actually handles only the drawing of the view itself. The children, if exist, are handled in a later stage of the drawing process, so I can do all the bitmap manipulations there.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the Bitmap until after View inflation is done. In other words, if it's in the xml layout, take it out and do what you need in Java.

EDIT: in light of your comment.

[Get the ViewTreeObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getViewTreeObserver%28%29), like so:

```
ViewTreeObserver theObserver = viewGroup.getViewTreeObserver();
```

Then add whatever listener you need to the [ViewTreeObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html).

Comment: I don't have an XML layout, I'm adding the children dynamically. My question is how I can intercept the drawing process before the parent draws itself and get the bitmap it's supposed to draw in order to rotate it, and only after that call the children to draw themselves.

Comment: You most likely need to add an OnPreDrawListener to the ViewTreeObserver to intercept the drawing process.

Comment: But the `onPreDraw` function doesn't get any arguments, so how can I get the bitmap of the view?